# WordPress function get_row() doesn't work properly

Tags: wordpress, function, member

I got problem with function  get_row() in WordPress and can't find satisfied answer for my situation. That is a piece of my code

```
 function take_category() {

    $table_result = array(); 
       $connect_to = connect_to_db(); 
    $question = "select id_cat, name_cat from category";
     if (!($result=$connect_to->get_results($question, ARRAY_N))) {
        return false;
   } 
   $prepared_row =$connect_to->prepare("%s", $question);
   var_dump($prepared_row);
      $row=$conntect_to->get_row($prepared_row, ARRAY_N, 1); // line 689
     var_dump($row).'</br>';
   for ($count=0; $row=$conntect_to->get_row($question, ARRAY_N, 1); 
 $count++) {
   $table_result[$count] = $row;
         .........
  return $table_result;
```

this function is placed into **functions.php**. Function **connect_to_db()** is defined in this file as well:

```
 function connect_to_db() {
  global $wpdb; 
   $wpdb = new wpdb('****', '', '****store', 'localhost');
     if (!$wpdb) {
       return false;
    } else{
     $wpdb->query('SET autocommit = 1;');
   return $wpdb;
  }
 }
```

Connection to Database is worked properly. Function **prepare** works correctly as well. This is **var_dump($prepared_row):**

```
string(39) "'select id_cat, name_cat from category'"
```

But next piece of code

```
$row=$conntect_to->get_row($prepared_row, ARRAY_N, 1); // line 689
 var_dump($row);
```

shows result  **NULL**: and fatal error

```
***Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_row() on 
null in ....\functions.php:689 Stack trace: #0 ...\indeks.php(12): 
take_category() #1 {main} thrown in ...\functions.php on line 689*
```

File **indeks.php** is a file where function **take_category()** is called:

```
 $cat_table = take_category();
```

But if I changes my line 689 like this:

```
  $row=$connect_to->get_row("select id_cat, name_cat from category", 
 ARRAY_N, 1);
```

I see  **var_dump($row):**

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(9) "Textbooks" }
```

and the same fatal error!

What is wrong with function **get_row**?

Dear gentelments i found the problem. Sorry for waisting your time...

Answer (score 0):

Should `$conntect_to->get_row()` not be `$connect_to->get_row()`?

Comment: Dear gentelmen! Thank you for reply. I wrote i found this mistake and correct it. Unfortunately i wasn't able to delete my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Variable is mispelled. You set `$connect_to` earlier. However now you are accessing `$conntect_to`. Rename it to `$connect_to`.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error in `conntect_to->` and `connect_to->`. Use it carefully.